# MVC redirecting folder to page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have page:
localhost/Transport/Index - which is my main page.

Now when I go to
localhost/Transport - I get error that page is not found.

Note that Transport is a "folder"

How can I redirect that to Index or any other page?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem because of same name of Controller and any Folder. To resolve this I added a handler to my web.config, handler section.

```
    <add name="ApiURIs-Transport-Integrated-4.0" path="YOURCONTROLLERNAME/*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Hope it will help.